# Font files PhoneGap - build error

Tags: android, css, cordova, fonts, phonegap-build

I'm new to PhoneGap, and converting a website to PhoneGap app. I'm using PhoneGap 5.1.1 CLI, everything is fine except I cannot use FontAwesome and Bootstrap CSS fonts.

When included the font files .woff etc, it produces `Execution failed for task :processDebugResources` error during `phonegap build android`

FontAwesome and Bootstrap are in the CSS folder.

How do you use them?

I already checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30645900) but it doesn't help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ionic build android failure - Execution failed for task processDebugResources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30645900/ionic-build-android-failure-execution-failed-for-task-processdebugresources)

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I had already checked that question, it didn't help me.

Comment: Ok, I was needed to trying :)