# Android Build Failed - Ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I have installed ionic and trying to build android to ionic. However, I face the below error.

> execution failed for task:cordovalib:processdebugresources [Build failed exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ycjQ.png)

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737200/execution-failed-appprocessdebugresources-android-studio, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30645900/ionic-build-android-failure-execution-failed-for-task-processdebugresources

Comment: update node for your platform

Comment: can you please help on how to update the node for the android platform.