# Error 'features.h' file not found in QTCreator in a Android Project

Tags: android, qt, android-ndk, qt-creator

I am trying to compile an application for Android via QTCreator.
In particular a toolkit Qt 5.12.10 Clang arm64-v8a

I got this error message:

```
In file included from C:/Qt/5.12.10/android_arm64_v8a/include/QtCore\QObject:1:

In file included from C:/Qt/5.12.10/android_arm64_v8a/include/QtCore/qobject.h:46:

In file included from C:/Qt/5.12.10/android_arm64_v8a/include\QtCore/qobjectdefs.h:48:

In file included from C:/Qt/5.12.10/android_arm64_v8a/include\QtCore/qnamespace.h:43:

In file included from C:/Qt/5.12.10/android_arm64_v8a/include\QtCore/qglobal.h:45:

In file included from D:\android\sdk\ndk\23.1.7779620/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include
\type_traits:416:

D:\android\sdk\ndk\23.1.7779620/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include\__config:218:12: fatal error: 

'features.h' file not found
```

In my last try I dowloaded sdk and ndk using Android Studio.
The versions of NDK that I have tried are 21, 22, 23 and 25

The JDK is jdk1.8.0_341.

All my Android 'Kits' in preferences->devices->Android have a warning about "No device set"

**Edited**:

Following the sugestions from Alexander Dyagilev worked.
However I had issues with gradle and SDK.
Then I have installed SDK 11 and gradle 7.0.2 and I advanced some steps further but yet I have erros.

My build.gradle is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    mavenCentral()
    google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
}

android {
    /*******************************************************
     * The following variables:
     * - androidBuildToolsVersion,
     * - androidCompileSdkVersion
     * - qt5AndroidDir - holds the path to qt android files
     *                   needed to build any Qt application
     *                   on Android.
     *
     * are defined in gradle.properties file. This file is
     * updated by QtCreator and androiddeployqt tools.
     * Changing them manually might break the compilation!
     *******************************************************/

    compileSdkVersion androidCompileSdkVersion.toInteger()

    buildToolsVersion androidBuildToolsVersion

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = [qt5AndroidDir + '/src', 'src', 'java']
            aidl.srcDirs = [qt5AndroidDir + '/src', 'src', 'aidl']
            res.srcDirs = [qt5AndroidDir + '/res', 'res']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
       }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.comm5.visaocloud"
        }
}
```

The build log is:

```
16:17:33: Running steps for project cloudclient...
16:17:33: Starting: "C:\Users\Paoli\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.3.6528147\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\make.exe" clean -j16
del qrc_cloudclient_qmlcache.cpp
del qml_visaocloud_js.cpp qml_main_qml.cpp qml_content_LoginScreen_qml.cpp qml_content_ButtonControl_qml.cpp qml_content_SettingsScreen_qml.cpp qml_content_OeeIndice_qml.cpp qml_content_StackInformation_qml.cpp qml_content_MachineWidgetDelegateAutomatico_qml.cpp qml_content_DashboardScreen_qml.cpp qml_content_LineInformation_qml.cpp qml_content_FlipEffectImage_qml.cpp qml_content_MachineWidgetDelegateManual_qml.cpp qml_content_OeeMachineWidget_qml.cpp qml_content_DashboardUtils_js.cpp
del qmlcache_loader.cpp
del moc_predefs.h
del moc_dashboardlistmodel.cpp moc_notificationengine.cpp moc_hardwareutils.cpp moc_qjsonmodelarray.cpp
del main.moc
del main.obj dashboardlistmodel.obj deviceregistration.obj notificationengine.obj hardwareutils.obj JsonPath.obj qjsonmodelarray.obj deviceregistration_android.obj hardwareutils_android.obj qrc_cloudclient_qmlcache.obj qml_visaocloud_js.obj qml_main_qml.obj qml_content_LoginScreen_qml.obj qml_content_ButtonControl_qml.obj qml_content_SettingsScreen_qml.obj qml_content_OeeIndice_qml.obj qml_content_StackInformation_qml.obj qml_content_MachineWidgetDelegateAutomatico_qml.obj qml_content_DashboardScreen_qml.obj qml_content_LineInformation_qml.obj qml_content_FlipEffectImage_qml.obj qml_content_MachineWidgetDelegateManual_qml.obj qml_content_OeeMachineWidget_qml.obj qml_content_DashboardUtils_js.obj qmlcache_loader.obj moc_dashboardlistmodel.obj moc_notificationengine.obj moc_hardwareutils.obj moc_qjsonmodelarray.obj
del *~ core *.core
NÆo foi poss¡vel encontrar D:\programming\comm5\visao\b-cloudclient-And_Qt_5_12_10_Clarmv7aRelease\*~
16:17:35: The process "C:\Users\Paoli\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.3.6528147\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\make.exe" exited normally.
16:17:35: Starting: "C:\Qt\5.12.10\android_armv7\bin\qmake.exe" D:\programming\comm5\visao\cloudclient\cloudclient.pro -spec android-clang "CONFIG+=qtquickcompiler"
16:17:37: The process "C:\Qt\5.12.10\android_armv7\bin\qmake.exe" exited normally.
16:17:37: Starting: "C:\Users\Paoli\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.3.6528147\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\make.exe" -f D:/programming/comm5/visao/b-cloudclient-And_Qt_5_12_10_Clarmv7aRelease/Makefile qmake_all
make: Nothing to be done for 'qmake_all'.
16:17:38: The process "C:\Users\Paoli\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.3.6528147\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\make.exe" exited normally.
16:17:38: Starting: "C:\Users\Paoli\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.3.6528147\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\make.exe" -j16
C:\Users\Paoli\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++ -D__ANDROID_API__=16 -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi -gcc-toolchain C:\Users\Paoli\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.3.6528147/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 -fno-limit-debug-info -DANDROID_HAS_WSTRING --sysroot=C:\Users\Paoli\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.3.6528147/sysroot -isystem C:\Users\Paoli\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.3.6528147/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -isystem C
.....


16:17:44: The process "C:\Users\Paoli\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.3.6528147\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\make.exe" exited normally.
16:17:44: Removing directory D:\programming\comm5\visao\b-cloudclient-And_Qt_5_12_10_Clarmv7aRelease\android-build/assets
16:17:44: Removing directory D:\programming\comm5\visao\b-cloudclient-And_Qt_5_12_10_Clarmv7aRelease\android-build/libs
16:17:44: Starting: "C:\Users\Paoli\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.3.6528147\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\make.exe" "INSTALL_ROOT=D:\programming\comm5\visao\b-cloudclient-And_Qt_5_12_10_Clarmv7aRelease\android-build" install && cd D:\programming\comm5\visao\b-cloudclient-And_Qt_5_12_10_Clarmv7aRelease && C:\Users\Paoli\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.3.6528147\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\make.exe "INSTALL_ROOT=D:\programming\comm5\visao\b-cloudclient-And_Qt_5_12_10_Clarmv7aRelease\android-build" install
C:\Qt\5.12.10\android_armv7\bin\qmake.exe -install qinstall -exe ..\bin\deploy\libcloudclient.so D:\programming\comm5\visao\b-cloudclient-And_Qt_5_12_10_Clarmv7aRelease\android-build\libs\armeabi-v7a\libcloudclient.so
C:\Qt\5.12.10\android_armv7\bin\qmake.exe -install qinstall -exe ..\bin\deploy\libcloudclient.so D:\programming\comm5\visao\b-cloudclient-And_Qt_5_12_10_Clarmv7aRelease\android-build\libs\armeabi-v7a\libcloudclient.so
16:17:48: The process "C:\Users\Paoli\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.3.6528147\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\make.exe" exited normally.
16:17:48: Starting: "C:\Qt\5.12.10\android_armv7\bin\androiddeployqt.exe" --input D:/programming/comm5/visao/b-cloudclient-And_Qt_5_12_10_Clarmv7aRelease/android-libcloudclient.so-deployment-settings.json --output D:/programming/comm5/visao/b-cloudclient-And_Qt_5_12_10_Clarmv7aRelease/android-build --android-platform android-21 --jdk "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.16" --gradle
Generating Android Package
  Input file: D:/programming/comm5/visao/b-cloudclient-And_Qt_5_12_10_Clarmv7aRelease/android-libcloudclient.so-deployment-settings.json
  Output directory: D:/programming/comm5/visao/b-cloudclient-And_Qt_5_12_10_Clarmv7aRelease/android-build/
  Application binary: D:/programming/comm5/visao/bin/deploy/libcloudclient.so
  Android build platform: android-21
  Install to device: No
Warning: This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 2 but an SDK XML file of version 3 was encountered. This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the command-line tools that were released at different times.
Warning: elemento inesperado (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Os elementos esperados são <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level>
  -- Skipping C:/Qt/5.12.10/android_armv7/plugins/iconengines/libqsvgicon.so. It has unmet dependencies: lib/libQt5Svg.so.
  -- Skipping C:/Qt/5.12.10/android_armv7/plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.so. It has unmet dependencies: lib/libQt5Svg.so.
> Task :preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileDebugRenderscript
> Task :generateDebugBuildConfig
> Task :javaPreCompileDebug
> Task :checkDebugAarMetadata
> Task :generateDebugResValues
> Task :generateDebugResources
> Task :compileDebugAidl FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugAidl'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AidlCompile$AidlCompileRunnable
   > > Task :mergeDebugResources
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\Paoli\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\33.0.0\aidl.exe with arguments {-pC:\Users\Paoli\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-21\framework.aidl -oD:\programming\comm5\visao\b-cloudclient-And_Qt_5_12_10_Clarmv7aRelease\android-build\build\generated\aidl_source_output_dir\debug\out -IC:\Qt\5.12.10\android_armv7\src\android\java\src -ID:\programming\comm5\visao\b-cloudclient-And_Qt_5_12_10_Clarmv7aRelease\android-build\src -ID:\programming\comm5\visao\b-cloudclient-And_Qt_5_12_10_Clarmv7aRelease\android-build\aidl -ID:\programming\comm5\visao\b-cloudclient-And_Qt_5_12_10_Clarmv7aRelease\android-build\src\debug\aidl -IC:\Users\Paoli\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\48a46c27b0d9b79f33541fa222ce4db4\transformed\support-media-compat-26.1.0\aidl -IC:\Users\Paoli\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\192ad8f6a0f651ff9f10305663e68198\transformed\support-compat-28.0.0\aidl -IC:\Users\Paoli\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\5d596afbbf514aaec8702eb472ca97f3\transformed\versionedparcelable-28.0.0\aidl -dC:\Users\Paoli\AppData\Local\Temp\aidl14331251136729576369.d C:\Qt\5.12.10\android_armv7\src\android\java\src\org\kde\necessitas\ministro\IMinistro.aidl}

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
7 actionable tasks: 7 executed
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: br.com.comm5
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Extras.Private.CppUtils
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Extras.Private.CppUtils
Building the android package failed!
  -- For more information, run this command with --verbose.
16:18:28: The process "C:\Qt\5.12.10\android_armv7\bin\androiddeployqt.exe" exited with code 14.
Error while building/deploying project cloudclient (kit: Android Qt 5.12.10 Clang armeabi-v7a)
The kit Android Qt 5.12.10 Clang armeabi-v7a has configuration issues which might be the root cause for this problem.
When executing step "Build Android APK"
16:18:28: Elapsed time: 00:56.
```

I hade also executed the command:

```
gradlew.bat --info  build clean --stacktrace
```

The result is

```
Initialized native services in: C:\Users\Paoli\.gradle\native
Found daemon DaemonInfo{pid=25160, address=[c2b63990-e0d8-4817-ad20-5308929c843b port:53261, addresses:[/127.0.0.1]], state=Idle, lastBusy=1660756380138, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=badf4a2e-2eb1-4075-bba8-1291894fe5dd,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_281,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\Paoli\.gradle\daemon,pid=25160,idleTimeout=10800000,priority=NORMAL,daemonOpts=-Xmx2048m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=BR,-Duser.language=pt,-Duser.variant]} however its context does not match the desired criteria.
Java home is different.
Wanted: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=null,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.16,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\Paoli\.gradle\daemon,pid=77640,idleTimeout=null,priority=NORMAL,daemonOpts=--add-opens,java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.nio.charset=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED,-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xms256m,-Xmx512m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=BR,-Duser.language=pt,-Duser.variant]
Actual: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=badf4a2e-2eb1-4075-bba8-1291894fe5dd,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_281,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\Paoli\.gradle\daemon,pid=25160,idleTimeout=10800000,priority=NORMAL,daemonOpts=-Xmx2048m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=BR,-Duser.language=pt,-Duser.variant]

  Looking for a different daemon...
Found daemon DaemonInfo{pid=42916, address=[f37e5b97-0c13-437c-9fa9-cb3379a13472 port:58153, addresses:[/127.0.0.1]], state=Idle, lastBusy=1660768619876, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=feb33525-5510-4ed1-b91a-1d728494e115,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.16,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\Paoli\.gradle\daemon,pid=42916,idleTimeout=10800000,priority=NORMAL,daemonOpts=--add-opens,java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.nio.charset=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED,-Xmx2048m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=BR,-Duser.language=pt,-Duser.variant]} however its context does not match the desired criteria.
At least one daemon option is different.
Wanted: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=null,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.16,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\Paoli\.gradle\daemon,pid=77640,idleTimeout=null,priority=NORMAL,daemonOpts=--add-opens,java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.nio.charset=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED,-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xms256m,-Xmx512m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=BR,-Duser.language=pt,-Duser.variant]
Actual: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=feb33525-5510-4ed1-b91a-1d728494e115,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.16,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\Paoli\.gradle\daemon,pid=42916,idleTimeout=10800000,priority=NORMAL,daemonOpts=--add-opens,java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.nio.charset=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED,--add-opens,java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED,-Xmx2048m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=BR,-Duser.language=pt,-Duser.variant]

  Looking for a different daemon...
The client will now receive all logging from the daemon (pid: 56268). The daemon log file: C:\Users\Paoli\.gradle\daemon\7.0.2\daemon-56268.out.log
Starting 15th build in daemon [uptime: 2 hrs 27 mins 22.878 secs, performance: 100%, non-heap usage: 30% of 256 MiB]
Using 16 worker leases.
Now considering [D:\programming\comm5\visao\cloudclient\native\android] as hierarchies to watch
Not watching anything anymore
Watching the file system is enabled if available
Starting Build
Settings evaluated using settings file 'D:\programming\comm5\visao\cloudclient\native\android\settings.gradle'.
Projects loaded. Root project using build file 'D:\programming\comm5\visao\cloudclient\native\android\build.gradle'.
Included projects: [root project 'android']

> Configure project :
Evaluating root project 'android' using build file 'D:\programming\comm5\visao\cloudclient\native\android\build.gradle'.
Invalidating in-memory cache of C:\Users\Paoli\.gradle\caches\journal-1\file-access.bin
Invalidating in-memory cache of C:\Users\Paoli\.gradle\caches\7.0.2\fileHashes\fileHashes.bin
Invalidating in-memory cache of C:\Users\Paoli\.gradle\caches\7.0.2\fileHashes\resourceHashesCache.bin

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
Not watching anything anymore
Watched directory hierarchies: []
```

And the error from this same command (2>gradle_error.txt)

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'D:\programming\comm5\visao\cloudclient\native\android\build.gradle' line: 44

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Could not get unknown property 'androidCompileSdkVersion' for extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.

* Try:
Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:93)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.lambda$apply$0(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:133)
    at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:77)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:136)

....

==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

* Try:
Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.wrapException(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:75)
```

My androidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<manifest package="com.comm5.visaocloud" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionName="1.5.64" android:versionCode="12" android:installLocation="auto">
    <application android:debuggable="false" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtApplication" android:label="Visao Cloud" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|uiMode|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection|locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation" android:name="com.comm5.visaocloud.MainActivity" android:label="Visao Cloud" android:screenOrientation="unspecified" android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="-- %%INSERT_APP_LIB_NAME%% --"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.qt_sources_resource_id" android:resource="@array/qt_sources"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.repository" android:value="default"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.qt_libs_resource_id" android:resource="@array/qt_libs"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundled_libs_resource_id" android:resource="@array/bundled_libs"/>
            <!-- Deploy Qt libs as part of package -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundle_local_qt_libs" android:value="-- %%BUNDLE_LOCAL_QT_LIBS%% --"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundled_in_lib_resource_id" android:resource="@array/bundled_in_lib"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundled_in_assets_resource_id" android:resource="@array/bundled_in_assets"/>
            <!-- Run with local libs -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.use_local_qt_libs" android:value="-- %%USE_LOCAL_QT_LIBS%% --"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.libs_prefix" android:value="/data/local/tmp/qt/"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.load_local_libs" android:value="-- %%INSERT_LOCAL_LIBS%% --"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.load_local_jars" android:value="-- %%INSERT_LOCAL_JARS%% --"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.static_init_classes" android:value="-- %%INSERT_INIT_CLASSES%% --"/>
            <!--  Messages maps -->
            <meta-data android:value="@string/ministro_not_found_msg" android:name="android.app.ministro_not_found_msg"/>
            <meta-data android:value="@string/ministro_needed_msg" android:name="android.app.ministro_needed_msg"/>
            <meta-data android:value="@string/fatal_error_msg" android:name="android.app.fatal_error_msg"/>
            <!--  Messages maps -->
            <!-- Splash screen -->
            <!--
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.splash_screen_drawable" android:resource="@drawable/logo"/>
            -->
            <!-- Splash screen -->
            <!-- Background running -->
            <!-- Warning: changing this value to true may cause unexpected crashes if the
                          application still try to draw after
                          "applicationStateChanged(Qt::ApplicationSuspended)"
                          signal is sent! -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.background_running" android:value="false"/>
            <!-- Background running -->
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <!-- [START gcm_receiver] -->
        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
                <category android:name="com.comm5.visaocloud"/>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!-- [END gcm_receiver] -->
        <!-- [START gcm_listener] -->
        <service android:name="com.comm5.visaocloud.MyGcmListenerService">
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="-- %%INSERT_APP_LIB_NAME%% --"/>
        </service>
        <!-- [END gcm_listener] -->
        <!-- [START instanceId_listener] -->
        <service android:name="com.comm5.visaocloud.MyInstanceIDListenerService">
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="-- %%INSERT_APP_LIB_NAME%% --"/>
        </service>
        <!-- [END instanceId_listener] -->
        <service android:name="com.comm5.visaocloud.RegistrationIntentService">
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="-- %%INSERT_APP_LIB_NAME%% --"/>
        </service>
    </application>

    <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" android:smallScreens="true"/>

    <!-- The following comment will be replaced upon deployment with default permissions based on the dependencies of the application.
         Remove the comment if you do not require these default permissions. -->
    <!-- %%INSERT_PERMISSIONS -->

    <!-- The following comment will be replaced upon deployment with default features based on the dependencies of the application.
         Remove the comment if you do not require these default features. -->
    <!-- %%INSERT_FEATURES -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

    <permission android:name="com.comm5.visaocloud.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.comm5.visaocloud.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>
</manifest>
```

My QtCreator Project manager
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by an unsupported version of NDK. You need to:

1. Install the proper version of Android NDK in Android Studio (21.3.6528147) for Qt 5.12.
2. Make sure it's selected by default in Qt Creator's settings.
   Here is my screenshot with the settings. Default NDK is written using italic font.
   [image]
3. An optional thing, probably it's required to specify `ANDROID_NDK_PLATFORM` environment variable also. You can change it in Qt Creator's settings, but I suggest to set it globally (in the system's env variables). Its value should be `android-21`.
   [image]

P.S. Do not forget to clean & rebuild project after all these changes.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander, It seems that your suggestions solved the problem. I am not sure yet because of other problems (I think it is about the gradle) that has not to do with the subject of this post

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of changes I finaly was able to build the .apk file.
I do not know among all the changes which was relevant and which not.

Some posts I have used are:
[Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'. and a sugestions about how test gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30645900/ionic-build-android-failure-execution-failed-for-task-processdebugresources)

[About Sdk Version in build.gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50530889/gradle-sync-failed-cause-compilesdkversion-is-not-specified)

My build.gradle is now

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    mavenCentral()
    google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
}

android {
    /*******************************************************
     * The following variables:
     * - androidBuildToolsVersion,
     * - androidCompileSdkVersion
     * - qt5AndroidDir - holds the path to qt android files
     *                   needed to build any Qt application
     *                   on Android.
     *
     * are defined in gradle.properties file. This file is
     * updated by QtCreator and androiddeployqt tools.
     * Changing them manually might break the compilation!
     *******************************************************/

    compileSdkVersion 28 // androidCompileSdkVersion.toInteger()

    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2' // androidBuildToolsVersion

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = [qt5AndroidDir + '/src', 'src', 'java']
            aidl.srcDirs = [qt5AndroidDir + '/src', 'src', 'aidl']
            res.srcDirs = [qt5AndroidDir + '/res', 'res']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
       }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.comm5.visaocloud"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 29
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
}
```

I will study the Gradle documentation to avoid this annoying problema again. If someone has a suggestion about reading I will be grateful.